# How can I make as3 gotoAndStop/gotoAndPlay commands, believe that Mc.currentFrame==Mc.frame1;?

Tags: actionscript-3

I thank you in advance for your time and consideration. Add on making this site in the first place. :) I am trying to create a board game app. I would like to make each piece move by dice total number, instead of frame number. Is this possible, I have found nothing like it on the internet thus far. If I am asking the question wrong, please let me know. :) Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do this, specifically? It's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: What fish2000 wrote you. The question is very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

```
var diceValue = 4;
var stepDistance = 100;
piece.x += stepDistance * diceValue; //piece moves 400 pixels to the right
```